# Why is it sufficient to show that X has a simply-connected covering space in order to prove that $p_{*}$ is surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Hatcher page 63 states that as $p_{*}$ is always injective, trying to show that it is surjective amounts to finding a simply-connected covering space for X.  Can someone possibly explain the logic behind why that is sufficient?

Comment: The form in which the question is asked now, greatly reduces the amount of people which can help you to those who have the book available and are willing to open it just to answer your question. Try including more details please. For a beginning, what is $p^*$?

Comment: @M.Winter It's easy to get the book (https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).  The point about being willing to open it is perfectly valid, however.

Answer (score 2):

I just happened to have the book handy, but more information would be helpful in the future to those who do not.

Hatcher is not referring to showing that $p_*$ is surjective, he's referring to the function that associates the covering space $(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0},p)$ (where $p$ is the covering map) to the subgroup $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0}))$.

That is, the function is really something like $$\Phi: \mathcal{C}(X,x_0) \to \mathcal{S}(\pi_1(X,x_0)), \Phi(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0},p) = p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0})).$$

where $\mathcal{C}(X,x_0)$ is the set of covering spaces of $(X,x_0)$ and $S(\pi_1(X,x_0))$ is the set of subgroups of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. He wants to answer the question, "is every subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ realized this way"? That is, is $\Phi$ surjective? In particular, he wants to know if there's some covering space that the function $\Phi$ sends to the trivial subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. We then note that $p_*$ is always injective, so $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0}))$ being the trivial subgroup in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ means that $\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0})$ is the trivial group itself -- meaning that $(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0},p)$ is simply-connected.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that points of $\tilde{X}$ correspond to homotopy classes of paths based at $x_0$.

Suppose there exists a covering space $\tilde{X}$ that is simply connected. We claim that to every subgroup $G \subset \pi_1(X)$ there exists a cover $X_G$ such that $p_*(\pi_1 (X_G))=G$. First note that $G$ acts on $\tilde{X}$ by the restriction of the monodromy action. We first claim that $\tilde{X}/G$ is a covering space. Note that the resulting space is a quotient by $[\rho] \sim [\alpha]$ iff they have the same endpoint and $[\rho \cdot \overline{\alpha}] \in G$. This is a covering space (as you can check.)

Let $\tilde{x_0}$ "be" the homotopy class of the constant loop at $x_0$. If $[\rho] \in G$, then it lifts to a loop in $X_G$, and likewise if $\alpha \in X_G$ is a loop, then $[p \circ \alpha]$ is a loop in $X$ and $[p \circ \alpha] \in G.$